# How to interpret nodejs repl custom evaluation function signature?

Tags: node.js, read-eval-print-loop

I couldn't find any [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/repl.html#repl_custom_evaluation_functions) on the custom evaluation function. Anyone knows what each of the four parameters means?

```
// what are "cmd", "context", "filename", "callback"?
function myEval(cmd, context, filename, callback) {
  callback(null, myTranslator.translate(cmd));
}

repl.start({ prompt: '> ', eval: myEval });
```

Answer (score 2):

- `cmd` is the text the user inputs into the repl.
- `context` is the `context` property you can find inside your `replServer` instance. For example: `const myRepl = repl.start('$ '); myRepl.context;`
- `filename` I am not sure what it is.
- `callback` is a callback that needs to be executed in order to accept the command. It receives two attributes, the first one is an error if there are. The second one, is the text that will be printed on the screen.

The simplest implementation of a custom evaluator would be something like this:

```
function myEval(cmd, context, filename, callback) {
  callback(null, cmd);
}

repl.start({ prompt: '> ', eval: myEval });
```

That code will just print back whatever you write on the repl.